# Column wise role based security in asp.net mvc 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have asp.net MVC 4 application where I want to show columns based on the role. For example. Following is a my model class.

```
public class Employee
{
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public string FirstName {get;set;}
   public string LastName {get;set;}
   public string Designation {get;set;}
}
```

In my view I want to display the designation column only if the user is in the administrator role.

I can do that easily on the view by checking if the user is in the role. But that what I don't want to do. I want to establish security on column base. So If my user does not have admin rights, designation will be empty string.

Is this possible with ASP.NET MVC 4? Any help will be appreciated!.

Comment: something in the view needs to check that permission as it's not default, either you use the `GridView` component and override the `render` based on any custom Attributes that you will create on the `Designation` property, or create a Extension Method for it.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion!. Is there any example there for it?

Comment: What component or plugin are you using for your grid ?

Comment: I'm not using component plugin for grid. Simple for loop and show data.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of a way to do this in MVC 4, other than, as you say, do checks in the view.

What you could consider is rendering an entirely different view depending on the users role.

Of course, this might lead to other issues like repeated code etc, but it is an option.

Comment: still the purpose I was asking was not served!. I want security at column level. In your case designation will be still there but you are not displaying them.

Comment: You said "In my view I want to display the designation column only if the user is in the administrator role." This does that. Designation would not be displayed in the non-admin view.

Comment: Yes but still data is exposed to view. Think of a scenario where your view is developed by designer and he is not aware that this should be displayed or not. I want to restrict data.

Comment: Then you need a different view model for the view that does not have them property.

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar requirement in one of our projects, where in the reports table we had to hide certain column depending on the customer type.

Since our reports were loaded using ajax call, simple show/hide didnt make sense. Coz even though the data is hidden in the html, or say you remove or not render those column only on the html still the values would exist in the json response.

Instead here is what you could do.

Depending on user types you could have classes and these classes would have properties that you want to show to the users.

For example, you could start with a base class

```
public class EmployeeBase
{
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public string FirstName {get;set;}
   public string LastName {get;set;}
}
```

and then more specific ones.

```
public class EmployeeAdmin : EmployeeBase
{
   public string Designation {get;set;}
}
```

My class names might not be appropriate, but you get the idea.

Comment: That is good solution but in this solution will work if there is a few classes where you can control like this. But think about a big application where you hundreds of the model classes then you don't have time to create and maintain. I want something generic!

Comment: No. This cant be generic, since someone needs to define the data dimension based on the roles. One model class per role shouldnt be a problem. Incase you have 100 of roles, then it would be sensible to introduce rolegroups and make classes accordingly.